# Set up culture for input text box when writing number

Tags: c#, winforms, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I just using a kendo drop down list for my project

```
var editorElement = (RadDropDownListEditorElement)editor.EditorElement;
editorElement.KeyPress += EditorElement_KeyPress;
editorElement.FormatString = "D9";
```

This can use to input in both way, select data from drop down list & write directly from keyboard,I manage to localize number with `Value Member & Display Member` when choosing from list. But I'm stuck at this when use input from keyboard, whenever I input number it's always have default display like this

```
15769.9292
```

It only convert to current culture in my project when I switch to another window

```
15 769,9292 //fr-FR
15,769.9292 //en-US
```

Is there anyway that we can set up culture format even when we input number, like display comma instead of dot when we write number in French?

Comment: You may try to change Thread.CurrentCulture or Thread.CurrentUICulture properties.